# Como enviar un dato desde un textbox a un Web Service Php

Tags: c#, webservice, xamarin

Tengo una pequeña aplicación que funciona para ver datos desde un web service, la app funciona correctamente hasta que quise darle yo mismo el valor a buscar desde un textbox o entry, adjunto el codigo que estoy usando, al correrlo me sale todo en blanco aunque le de el valor y presione el botón buscar. Antes para que funcionara yo mismo le ponía el dato a buscar en la url pero ahora quiero que sea el usuario que ponga el dato en el textbox y al dar click en el botón buscar este envié el dato a la clase y así pueda ponerlo junto a la url para que está busque en el web service.

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="RESTFinal.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Entry Placeholder="Dato A Buscar" PlaceholderColor="Red" x:Name="prod_pos" />
            <Picker x:Name="picker"
        Title="Buscar Por"
        TitleColor="Red">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Cod. Barra</x:String>
                        <x:String>Id</x:String>
                        <x:String>Nombre</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
            <Button Text="Buscar" Clicked="Submit_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ListaCursos" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="40">
                            <Label Text="Codigo de Barras" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding InvCba}"/>
                            <Label Text="Descripcion" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding InvDesLar}"/>
                            <Label Text="Cantidad en Bodega" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding SalCan}"/>
                            <Label Text="Costo" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding SalCos}"/>
                            <Label Text="Venta" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding GaiPre}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RESTFinal
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LlenarCursos();

        }
        string nameValue { get; set; }

        private void Submit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nameValue = prod_pos.Text;
        }

        private async void LlenarCursos()
        {
            HttpClient Cliente = new HttpClient();

            String url = "http://192.168.0.9/Wsprueba.php?prod_pos="+ nameValue;
            var resultado = await Cliente.GetAsync(url);
            var json = resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            Consulta modelo = Consulta.FromJson(json);
            ListaCursos.ItemsSource = modelo.Producto;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Haz comprobado que la url y el parámetro arrojen el resultado, por medio de un navegador o de postman?

Comment: @HomeroRivera si pongo la url desde el navegador con cualquier dato que le dé me devuelve respuesta en JSON pero no sé si es que tengo alguna linea de código mal escrita en la app

Comment: Estás llamando a LlenarCursos() desde el constructor, y deberías llamarlo desde Submit_Clicked(...).

Además, LlenarCursos() no tiene parámetros, y necesitas pasarle el dato nameValue. La verdad me sorprende que este programa no esté fallando al tratar de compilar.

Comment: Podrías explicarme bien como arreglarlo en el código, no logro entender que tengo que cambiar.

Comment: ¿Sabes lo que es un constructor?

Comment: Supongo que te refieres al método principal

Comment: public MainPage() es tu constructor. Un constructor es un metodo que 1) se corre en automático al iniciar una instancia de una clase y que 2) no debe devolver ningún valor. En tu caso invocas a LlenarCursos() desde el constructor, cuando en realidad querrías invocarlo cuando el usuario presione el botón.

Comment: Te recomiendo que busques materil de aprendizaje a los siguientes conceptos de C# : clase, constructor, método, parámetros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que requieres usar el método LlenarCursos() cuando el usuario haga click, pero estás llamando a LlenarCursos() desde el constructor.

Además, LlenarCursos() no tiene acceso al valor del textbox o entry, por lo que LlenarCursos() necesita un parámetro...

O podrías poner todo el código de LlenarCursos() dentro del método Submit_Clicked().